# Issues in X and Y values in graphs created by Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

Both my X and Y axis are coming in form of 2.000e+7 and 1.5040e+7.
X axis is datetime like 2017-08-02 10:20:37.260
and Y axis should have integer values like 5000.

How can I correct this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0WOU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=450, tools=[hover, TOOLS], 
       title='Order/Execution Snapshot with Price Levels',
       x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='Price',x_axis_type="datetime")
```

X axis type as datetime helped solving the problem.